# Asking a potentially problematic follow-up question vs. unaccepting an answer

Tags: support, on-topic, duplicates, bounty

Some time ago, I asked the following question: [What is the relation between Tabaxi and ordinary cats?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166185/what-is-the-relation-between-tabaxi-and-ordinary-cats)

My question in the body text was a bit more nuanced, though:

> How closely are Tabaxi and ordinary cats related? Do they maybe have a special bond, or would they rather find each other a bit odd?

There is a perfectly fine answer to the title question, so I accepted it. However, it hardly provides any helpful information on the second part of the above quote. I had a brief exchange about that in the comments below this answer, and my last comment reads:

> It seems to me like Tabaxi resemble cats far more than humans resemble apes. It might feel odd to look at a creature that is essentially a smaller copy of oneself with an underdevelopped intellect. Maybe, for this reason, Tabaxi don't like to be associated with ordinary cats? Or maybe they just make them feel uncomfortable? I'm really not sure what to expect, so I was hoping that some rule book or adventure module mentions any kind of interaction between Tabaxi and ordinary cats.

Note that this is much more precise than what I wrote in the opening post, and I think I only got to the point of really understanding my own question in the process of this brief discussion.

Well, I am still interested in this kind of information, and I am kindly asking for advice on how to get it with the help of this community.

My thoughts about this so far:

I could ask a new question specifically about rule books or adventure modules mentioning anything about the interaction between Tabaxi and ordinary cats. But I'd be afraid that it would be considered as a duplicate of my existing question. I'm also not sure if it would be on topic at all (as I think I've read that existence questions are always at least borderline).

I could also un-accept the answer on the existing question and offer a bounty for giving a more detailed answer including the kind of information I am looking for. However, I feel that unaccepting an answer after so much time could be perceived as rude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Unaccept the answer and offer the bounty.

It isn't rude. It's the site functioning as intended - you've decided there is potential for better answers, so unaccepting the current answer "opens up" the question again, so to speak. On top of that, adding a bounty both encourages new answers and gives 1600hp, who is still an active user according to last seen, the opportunity to get those 15 points and more back.

Comment: If I choose to follow that path, would it be OK to edit the question slightly (roughly: add the comment I quoted above)?

Comment: Agreed. It sounds like that you realize that you were asking something and didn't get what you were expecting to get from the answer. the right thing to do is to put a bounty on it stating specifically what you think is missing.